# Topology - Product Space

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}$ have the usual topology.  Describe a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ that is open in the product space, but that is not a product of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

I understand that a subset $W$ in the product space $X$ x $Y$ is open iff, for each $(x,y) \in W$, there are open subsets $U$ and $V$ of $X$ and $Y$, for which $(x,y) \in U \times V \subseteq W$.

Isn't that saying the subset has to be the product of the open subsets $U$ and $V$?

Comment: No, it must be a union of open rectangles. The $U$ and $V$ depend (in general) on $x$ and $y$. Consider for example $(0,1)\times (0,1) \cup (3,4)\times(5,6)$.

Comment: Or for a more extreme example, $\{\langle x,y\rangle:x^2+y^2<1\}$, the open unit disk centred at the origin.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Do you mind elaborating a bit more to try and help me understand it a bit better?

Comment: Both Daniel’s set and mine are unions of open rectangles; his is the union of two, and mine is the union of infinitely many, but both are unions of open rectangles. If $W$ is one of our sets, and $\langle x,y\rangle\in W$, there are open sets $U$ and $V$ in $\Bbb R$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in U\times V$, and $U\times V\subseteq W$, so $W$ is open in the product topology.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Brilliant!  Thanks so much!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: @Brian M. Scott : I'm sorry to bother but I happened to come across this old thread. I'm not good with this product space material. In this case,  my confusion is why the sets inside your "open disk centered at the origin" creation are not a product of open subsets of R. Thanks.

Comment: @markleeds: I’m not sure what you’re asking: the sets $U\times V$ in my 2013 comment *are* products of open subsets of $\Bbb R$, though the open unit disk itself is not.

Comment: I'm sorry Brian for the confusion. The first paragraph of the OP's question says: "Describe a subset of $R^2 = R \times R$ that is open in the product space, but that is not a product of open subsets of ℝ". So, does the $U \times V$ in your example satisfy that. Thanks.

Comment: brian: I don't want you to spend so much time since this stuff is like kryptonite for me but can you recommend notes or a text that explains product spaces clearly. I've never found a good explanation but I have a lot of real analysis and measure theory books so I'm thinking that maybe one of them has a nice explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming from that statement that there should exist (x, y) in your W. What about {}? Your statement still holds, but there are no (x, y) in it. It is also true that it is an open space of W that is not the product of open subsets in X and Y.

Comment: This doesn’t work: $\varnothing=\varnothing\times\varnothing$ **is** a product of open sets in $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: You're right. Terrible slip on my part.